# С счетов или со щитов?

Tags: фразеология

Честно говоря, меня заклинило. Есть известная поговорка "сбрасывать со счетов (щитов)" - то есть забывать что-либо, отметать, не принимать во внимание.

И вот как все-таки она правильно звучит, о чем там идет речь: о щитах или о счетах. В принципе, логичен и первый, и второй вариант. На щитах носили раненых, плюс на них были гербы и т.д. Счета - вообще понятно.

Так все-таки о чем говорится в поговорке?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Со счетов, конечно: то, что набрано (счёт) - не считается, забыто - образовалось от прямого значения: в старину считали, набирая количество чего-то на дощечках с помощью маленьких фишек, а потом сбрасывали и забывали, новое набирали, потом появились деревянные счёты, здесь и вовсе понятно: набрал - сбросил.

http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/proverbs/44512/%D0%

http://phraseology.academic.ru/11145/%D0%

Сбрасывать со щитов - перефразированное значение, совсем другое - уничтожать врага.