# Со счетов или со щитов?

Tags: фразеология

Стала писать вроде бы известную фразу и споткнулась. Все-таки, как правильно: сбросить со СЧЕТОВ или со ЩИТОВ?
Смутно помню, что мне где-то попадалась информация, что можно и так, и этак, мол, это разные значения. И, если так, то в какой ситуации применяется каждый из вариантов?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Со "счетов", конечно (= нужно по-прежнему учитывать, принимать в расчёт что/кого-л.).Это один из случаев, когда часто возникает искажение с привлечением внешне похожего выражения. В данном случае это "со щитом или на щите". Другие распространённые мутации:

попал как кур во щи (курятину в щи когда-то не принято было класть) -> "попал как кур в ощип"

к родным пенатам (домой: пенаты - домашние фигурки языческих богов) -> "в родные пенаты" (искажение связано с известностью усадьбы Репина "Пенаты")

чему обязан (удовольствием вас видеть) -> "чем обязан (вам - что пришли)" - трансформация некогда вежливой фразы в грубый штапм

Answer (score 1):

Об этом уже говорили, речь о счетах:    [С счетов или со щитов?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/42635/%D1%84%)

Про щиты другой фразеологизм: Со щитом или на щите

С латинского: Aut cum scuto, aut in scuto [аут кум скуто, аут ин скуто].
Первоисточник выражения — сочинение древнегреческого историка Плутарха (ок. 45 — ок. 127) «Изречения лакедемонянок», в котором он сообщает о том, как спартанка Горго, провожая сына на битву с врагами, протянула ему щит и сказала: «С ним или на нем». Позднее это выражение стало употребляться (для большей ясности) в общеизвестной форме. Иными словами, спартанка Горго пожелала сыну или победить, или погибнуть (по обычаю, убитых обычно выносили с поля боя на их щитах). Плен, бегство для своего сына-спартанца она не допускала.
Иносказательно: или победить, добиться успеха, или проиграть, потерпеть неудачу в чем-либо.

Answer (score 0):

Был такой прибор, назывался счеты. Самый первый компьютер.  Там были косточки, которые передвигали туда сюда, как четки на веревочке, таким макаром считали: в магазинах, на рынках, в бухгалтериях,  везде были счеты.  Сбросить со счетов, это одним движением, перевернув, вернуть счеты в исходное состояние.

Comment: Вы это МНЕ рассказываете?)))) Да все мое детство в магазинах были ТОЛЬКО счеты))))